# Using get() with replacement functions

Tags: r, function, syntax, radix, replace

Can anyone explain to me why the following example occurs?

```
#Create simple dataframe
assign( "df" , data.frame( P = runif(5) , Q = runif(5) , R = runif(5) ) ) 

#Return the dataframe from the given character vector
get( "df" ) 
            P          Q          R
1  0.17396222 0.90994676 0.90590685
2  0.33860092 0.98078739 0.38058921
3  0.80751402 0.93229290 0.82853094
4  0.05460417 0.55448507 0.01605027
5  0.04250316 0.03808318 0.40678270

#Return the column names of df
colnames( get( "df" ) )
[1] "P" "Q" "R"

#But using a replacement function...
colnames( get( "df" ) ) <- c( "S" , "T" , "U" ) 
    Error in colnames(get("df")) <- c("S", "T", "U") : 
    target of assignment expands to non-language object
```

I'd 
**A)** like to know why the replacement functions won't work in this way with `get()`?

And **b)** if there is some way to work around this, given my problem which I outline below;

My problem is that I have many objects, created (using a toy example) in a loop, something like this: `assign( paste( "Object" , i , sep = "." ) , rnorm(1000 , i) )`, where `i` is a vector, say `i <- 1:1000` and then I would like to be able to assign names (for instance from a different vector) to each object in the loop, but `names( get( paste( "Object" , i , sep = "." ) ) <- someNewName` doesn't work as in the example above.

But `get( paste( "Object" , i , sep = "." ) )` does return the names (or `NULL`) of those objects.

Thanks!

Comment: For your specific question, try `setNames`. In general, I don't know why it doesn't work: I look forward to reading an edifying answer.

Comment: Thanks. I see that works using `assign()` and `setNames( get( "df" ) )`, however I am using a mcmc object from the coda package, which has a replacement function `varnames()` defined for changing variable names, which I need to use (unless I want to try and make my own - which is possible, I was just hoping to avoid it). I am still curious as to how the expression is evaluated though! Thanks.

Comment: Don't use `assign`. Put all objects created in your loop into a list instead. There is a good chance that you don't even need a `for` loop.

Comment: I know I probably don't need a `for` loop, it was just sheer convenience. Honestly, the overhead of calling the loop to create objects is minimal, < 0.1 seconds, so I'm not rigidly determined to vectorise everything in this case. It's a useful convenience construct that has it's place for the lazy coder (plus I'm doing a few other renaming assignments in the loop on different object, so it really is just convenient).

Comment: :hand waving: evaulation, blah blah blah, :more hand waving: Try `'colnames<-'(get('df'),c('A','B','C'))` and `colnames(data.frame( P = runif(5) , Q = runif(5) , R = runif(5) )) <- c('A','B','C')`

Comment: @SimonO101 I think you missed my point. I can't remember ever using `assign`. The way to go is a list holding the objects created in the loop.

Comment: I searched your error line "target of replacement expands to non-language object" and found some useful questions on Stack Overflow. Particularly [this link to the R FAQ](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#How-can-I-turn-a-string-into-a-variable_003f). Maybe `eval` and `substitute` will do the trick.

Comment: @Roland just because you never used it, does not mean it does not ever have it's place!

Comment: @SimonO101 I take your point to Roland, but in my view there has to be a really compelling reason to use `assign` and `get` rather than the more R-like paradigm of `lapply` and working with lists. I'd be keen to understand why you want to avoid working with lists.

Comment: While `assign` is sometimes useful, Roland is correct, you should almost certainly not be using it in the manner you've described.

Comment: @joran Thanks, your comment above is what I am looking for. I should remember in future, to Read-The-Manual. Specifically, pages 10 and 48 of S Programming! Thank you

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5365482/271616

Comment: @joran @Andrie @Roland I do agree with all of you! However, as I have previously stated, in this case should I really be making myself, HAVE to use lapply for something which has a tiny runtime and memory footprint anyway. The annoyance is in having many objects which I dont want to rename manually (the naming is just to do with displaying of variable names on plots), not in finding the most computer-efficient (CPU time, RAM) way to do it. It was more time-efficient for me to just use `for()`. I know I shouldn't, but I did. So shoot me! :-)

Comment: @SimonO101 `for` loops have their place, but once you understand `lapply` you realize that it is actually more convenient. The loop construct is not the most important lesson here, using a list is.

Comment: @joran @Andrie Can I delete the second half of my question? Because the what I am most interested in, is not how to side-step that error (but thanks and kudos for solving that for me), but someone stepping me through how `colnames( get( "df" ) ) <- (c1,2,3)` gets evaluated leading to the error. Thank you all.

Comment: @Roland ok, thanks, point taken. No more `for()` loops when I post on SO. But side-stepping the issue of using `for()` loops or `lists` (it's not really not what I am asking about) I'd love to understand how/why the last evaluation fails.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To understand why this doesn't work, you need to understand what `colnames<-` does. Like every function in that looks like it's modifying an object, it's actually modifying a copy, so conceptually `colnames(x) <- y` gets expanded to:

```
copy <- x
colnames(copy) <- y
x <- copy
```

which can be written a little more compactly if you call the replacement operator in the usual way:

```
x <- `colnames<-`(x, y)
```

So your example becomes

```
get("x") <- `colnames<-`(get("x"), y)
```

The right side is valid R, but the command as a whole is not, because you can't assign something to the result of a function:

```
x <- 1
get("x") <- 2
# Error in get("x") <- 2 : 
#  target of assignment expands to non-language object
```

Comment: Thank you very much for a clear and concise explanation to my question. This exactly what I was hoping for.

Comment: @SimonO101 Tweaked slightly to make more accurate.  There are a few more details at https://github.com/hadley/devtools/wiki/Functions (search for "replacement functions")

Comment: Thanks hadley - i'm heading over to devtools now!

Answer (score 11):

Using `assign` in the way you demonstrate in the question is at least uncommon in R. Normally you would just put all objects in a list.

So, instead of

```
for (i in 1:10) {
assign( paste( "Object" , i , sep = "." ) , rnorm(1000 , i) )}
```

you would do

```
objects <- list()
for (i in 1:10) {
objects[[i]] <- rnorm(1000 , i) }
```

In fact, this construct is so common that there is a (optimized) function (`lapply`), which does something similar:

```
objects <- lapply(1:10, function(x) rnorm(1000,x))
```

You can then access, e.g., the first object as `objects[[1]]` and there are several functions for working with lists.

Comment: Almost +1, and I will upvote if you also add the `lapply` version.

Comment: +1 `lapply()` is the way to go here. It will simplify code, and may even be faster than the for loop, simply because `<-` is a relatively slow operation.

Comment: @Andrie `<-` is not relatively slow: repeatedly modifying a complex data structure is slow. (And I don't think you'll see much difference here since IIRC `[[<-` is special-cased so it doesn't make a copy)

Comment: @hadley Sorry, your're correct. I should have written `[<-` is slow.  Some time ago I was able to create a much faster version of `read.fwf()` by replacing `[<-` with `lapply`.  I may be wrong in this analysis, but at the time this was my interpretation of my `rprof()` results.

Comment: @Andrie If you want to be even more precise, it's really `[<-.data.frame` that's slow. Also, `read.fwf` is a disaster that just about any change can make better ;)

Comment: @Andrie @hadley Considering the chastening discussion in my question above I have been looking at replacing `for` with `lapply`, however once I have constructed the `objects` list in the example above, how would I then go about replacing the names of each element in each vector, for each element in the list (considering the `names` vector for each list element is different), e.g. `names( objects[[1]] ) <- c(1:1000)` but `names( objects[[2]]) <- sample(letters , 1000 , replacement = TRUE)`. How do I lapply this? Maybe this is a seperate question with better example?