# replace/assign value in a data.frame accessed through get()

Tags: r, replace, assign

Just like the title, I would like to replace certain cells in a data.frame which is accessed through `get`, a reproducible example to clarify my question:

```
df <- data.frame( x = rnorm(10),
                  y = rnorm(10))
```

I want to replace, say the first element of column `x`, in `df` as 'A', which is quite easy in the common ways:

```
df[1,'x']<-NA
```

However, how could I do this if I have to access `df` through another function like `get`, what I want to do is something like:

```
get('df')[1,'x']<-NA
```

which will throw out an error:
 `target of assignment expands to non-language object`.
I searched here and other places on Google for a while, a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14464442/using-get-with-replacement-functions), but no solution so far.
Is this possible? How if it is.

**============ EDIT based on MKR's comment ===============**
here is the solution:

```
a<-get('df')
a[1,'x']<-NA
assign('df',a)
rm(a)
```

Comment: `get` function return the `df` and your code `get('df')[1,'x']<-NA` will work. Do you mean to use another custom `my_get` function written by you?

Comment: @MKR, did you try my code? it did not work on my machine. And one can't assign a value to an object returned by another function I guess.

Comment: What exactly I meant was that `get('df')` will give you `df` and then you can modify it per your choice. For example `a <- get('df');a[1,'x']<-NA`. Now is that what you want to do in a single line? Or you have any other function to use?

Comment: Having to use `get` often suggests you should be storing things in a list instead of as separate objects. Can you give some context for your question?

Comment: @MKR, yeah, that's a way doing it, sorry for my misunderstanding. I must have myself a cup of coffee to avoid such silly questions. I will re-edit the question based on your comment. Btw, is there a one-liner of this  problem?

Comment: @JasonGoal There can be couple of options to apply `<-` operator. I dont  know your context but say I could have used `dplyr` chain as `get("df") %>% mutate(x = ifelse(row_number()==1, NA, x))`

Comment: It is better to add your answer as an "answer" rather than in the question.

Comment: @dash2, you are correct on the `list` instead of `get` point, agree with you. I'm modifying an old stuff written years back.

Comment: @dash2, sure, if MKR is willing to post an answer, I would like to accept it and delete the solution part from my question. If not, I would like to keep it in the question, as the credit is not mine.

Comment: `assign('df', \`[<-\`(get('df'), 1, 'x', value = NA))`